# gcloud auth login does not update/identify my active account correctly for git usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have been trying to log with a new corporate account in order to push some code in **gcp Cloud Repository**. Despite all my attempts at logging in with the new user, somehow when I issue `git push` it still tells me

```
ERROR: Your current active account [old_email@domain.com] does not have any valid credentials
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials.

For service account, please activate it first:

  $ gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT
            Run 'gcloud auth login' to log in.
Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com':
```

When I run `gcloud auth list` only the new corporate email `<new_corporate_email>@domain.com` is displayed.

Here are the steps I took

- `gcloud auth login`
- `gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser`
- `gcloud auth application-default login`
- `gcloud config set account <new_corporate_email>@domain.com`
- `git config --global user.email "<new_corporate_email>@domain.com"`

Where is the current active account stored and how do I refresh its value? Could this be strictly a `git` issue?

Comment: The docs say the git config is created when you run `gcloud init`, and the documentation of that command note that it can also be used to reinitialize your config, so you might try that.

Comment: Try `gcloud auth revoke` first and the `gcloud auth login`. Or start over with `gcloud init`.

Comment: Have you tried `gcloud init`?

Comment: Hi all, yes I did try `gcloud init`, still getting the same error

Comment: The Git email is stored in .git/config. Are you trying to change the email of an existing GitHub project?

Comment: @JohnHanley, I did try that as you can see via the `git config` command. Idk if my attempt has a mistake, but I ended up fixing it by recloning.

Comment: `git config` affects future actions. To modify `user.email` of the current repository, do not use the `--global` flag.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to remember it next time. Nonetheless, the error message is misleading as it was not an issue of `gcloud auth login`.

Comment: Your question is confusing on what the problem is. Review the question title. Turns out you are trying to modify `git` and not Google Cloud authorization.

Comment: @JohnHanley, please review my answers. It is not a github repository, it is a gcp repo. Had my error stack been pointing me towards git, I would have asked my question differently, but I believe it is more useful for people encountering the same error to find a thread directly relating to gcloud,  which ultimately is the sdk that was used to clone the repo and sets all the dependencies of email, user, repo info etc...

Comment: Git, GitHub, Cloud Repository, GitBucket, GitLab, etc are the same technology family. The authorization may be different but the underlying APIs are the same. Cloud Repository uses the CLI `git` as well as other compatible tools. I think the problem you had was with the `.git/config` file which stores your repository details. The solution was probably `git config user.email XXX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected it was a problem with git and its relationship with `gcloud` since I am using **Google Cloud Source Repositories**.

What I did was not solve this solution perse, but I offer you a workaround in case you get the same error. Here are the steps I applied to "fix" it:

1. I made sure I was logged with the right account on `gcloud`
2. I made sure that account had the right IAM rights within the GCP
   project
3. I backed up my source repo (thankfully, only these few last changes
   were missing from my remote repo)
4. I deleted the original local source code repo and recloned it using
   `gcloud`
5. I took the changes from my backup folder via `rsync`
6. I tested a `commit` & `push` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `.git/config`
2. Find the line `helper = !gcloud auth git-helper --account=old_email@domain.com --ignore-unknown $@`
3. Change `--account=old_email@domain.com` to your new sign in email
4. [Optional] Change the email in `email = old_email@domain.com`

I got the exact same problem and this works for me. Thanks to [John Harley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley)'s comment which led me to look into the config file.